# Problem with Eclipse IMP Plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have just installed the IMP plugin for Eclipse but the IMP menus don't show up -for example, I can't see the IMP Perspective in the related area- I have followed the instructions at IMP website sharply -also used Eclipse SDK 3.3.2 as suggested in the EclipseCon 2009 tutorial presentation- and restarted Eclipse after installing the related IMP files but to no avail. The OS is Windows Vista,  Any suggestions on how I can solve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the IMP update-site?
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/imp/updates

No messages in the log-file?

You could try to start the bundles by hand to see if there are any dependency problems.

Go to the "Console"-View and change it to "OSGi Host".
then enter something like "ss imp".
Then you will see the relevant plugins and there state.
You can analyze the plugins with diag  like diag 57

Maybe this will throw messages about unresolved dependencies...

Comment: Your OSGi suggestion tipped me off to try installing the IMP on a newer Eclipse version -since the 3.3.2 and 3.4.2 that was suggested in the tutorial didn't have it- and I managed to make it work on Indigo 3.7. Thanks a lot.